# Mapinfo 10.5 and 8.5 compatibility? Unable to open TAB file

Tags: mapinfo, tab

I have recently submitted some data to a client as a TAB file. They are using v8.5 and I am using v10.5, the data is just one .TAB (with the associated other files). And all the field types are character, so I thought this wouldn't be an issue. Are there any other things I may have overlooked when saving my file?

Regards,
Alan

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you checked the TAB file itself? Right click on the saved .TAB file and open in Notepad or another basic text editor and see what the version number it has saved in the top is. It should look something like this.

```
!table
!version 450
!charset WindowsLatin1
```

If it says `!version1050` then it might be worth changing that to `!version850` (make sure you make a copy!) and see if that works.

Failing that you could export it as a Mid/Mif file and see if your client can import that instead.

Normally when I get these problems it is because I have used a Date/Time field which are not compatible with older versions, but since you say you only have Char fields this should not be a problem.

The Geometry might also be a problem if it happens to be really complex object types (multi-collections, text and so on) might struggle in older versions, although I doubt it, but you never know.

Comment: Thanks! Changing the version worked! I also tried a Mid/Mif earlier and that didn't work. Spent all morning searching the office for a copy of 8.5!

Comment: Also it was just points with 13 fields of characters, why would it save as v10? It it possible I did something at some point during the data processing before my final output that was incompatible with earlier versions?

Comment: You might have used a new feature, like the scale bar adornments for example, elsewhere and it jsut decided that v10 was what you needed everything in. Does seem strange though as most of mine save as v450 y default. Glad its fixed anyway!

Comment: We have added a number of things to MI Pro that would stamp a new version number in the header of the tab file in the recent number of versions, such as new coordinate systems, PostGIS and SQL Server linked tables, Office 2007 tables and the DateTime column. If you have used one of these the version will stay - MapInfo Pro doesn't "downgrade" the version in the header if you remove the "feature" later.

Comment: To see a list of added "version changing features", look in the Help System for "File Versions and TAB, MIF/MID, and WOR Support"